# Mac Mini WOL running Windows

Tags: windows-7, mac-mini, wake-on-lan

I am running Windows 7 on a Mac mini via bootcamp.  I can't seem to get wake on lan working at all.  Is there something I need to do to get this to work?

Testing it out on other windows 7 machines, WOL works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not relevant you've Win7 on Mac Mini Bootcamp. Other users (me too) have
problems with WOL..

Try this setting (for some users it worked, not for me unfortunately):

1) Open Terminal

2) `cd /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`

3) `sudo vi com.apple.Boot.plist`  (give administrative password)

4) modify `<string></string>` to `<string>darkwake=0</string>`

5) save & exit with `:wq`!

6) reboot & then shutdown the Mac Mini

7) on another computer send the WOL "Magic Packet" (I used WoLEX on Windows)

8) wait and.. hope!

I don't know if it doesn't work for me because of the shutdown instead of a "suspend"
But the Mac Mini is not a PowerBook, so I didn't find a "suspend" option..